# What are the roles of Brennan and Spiletto during Damien's birth?

Tags: movie, horror, the-omen

I recently watched *The Omen* (both the 1976 original and the 2006 remake), and I wonder why the hell (pun intended) father Brennan and father Spiletto were involved with the birth of Damien (The Antichrist), and more importantly, with the allocation of the child to a political figure (in order to ensure his future raising as a political ruler).

It is shown that Father Brennan (who tried to convince the U.S. ambassador about the evil nature of his "son" Damien) had the 666 mark, which is determined through a biopsy to be in fact a birthmark. What are the implications of this? does it means that Father Brennan was a potential (but later repented) Antichrist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[David Seltzer's novel](https://openlibrary.org/books/OL24215763M/The_omen), on which the movies were based, fleshes out the backstory of the priests' involvement.  The priests who participated in the switched child caper and the governess (who came on the scene after the first Thorn governess suicided) were all members of a cult of Satanists determined to bring the prophecy of the Anti-Christ to fruition.  The plan had been tried twice before in different centuries but was foiled each time by alert Christians.  The priests, for separate reasons, eventually repented of their actions and sought to atone for their wrongdoing.

In the novel the "Brennan" character was Father Tassone.  Tassone did not bear the mark of the Beast.  He was a leader in the Satanist cult but repented after developing cancer.  Fearing his own death he sought forgiveness for what he had done, namely the brutal killing of the Thorn newborn.

Spiletto was another leader of the cult.  In the novel he repented after being blinded and burned in a fire that razed the hospital where the original baby switch took place.